# crash in android application while in background

Tags: android

I am frequently facing a crash on my Galaxy S4 device running android 4.3. The crash stack is:

```
Segmentation fault
at <JNI>.#00  pc 00002d4c  /system/lib/libPowerStretch.so (LucidConfig::calcTargetFPS(int)+27)(Native Method)
at <JNI>.#01  pc 00002f23  /system/lib/libPowerStretch.so (LucidConfig::isLucidActive(bool)+134)(Native Method)
at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglReleaseThread(Native Method)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer$Gl20RendererEglContext.onTerminate(HardwareRenderer.java:1743)
at android.opengl.ManagedEGLContext.execTerminate(ManagedEGLContext.java:84)
at android.opengl.ManagedEGLContext.doTerminate(ManagedEGLContext.java:132)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.endTrimMemory(WindowManagerGlobal.java:460)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory(ActivityThread.java:4369)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is no clue from this crash stack that what is the problem. It seems OS crashed in some internal cleanup while calling `onTrimMemory`.
Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: This may well be a flaw in the system software, rather than an app under development.  The real key would be what is happening when it occurs.

Comment: There is no specific code. The app crashes sometimes when my app is in background and some other app is launched.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. Have you found a solution in the end? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I see a lot of this kind of "white noise". There are a lot of random crashes on different phones. Each manufacturer adds another layer of abstraction, and modifies "Android" in some way and finds himself with new crashes.

Feel free to ignore it. Not only its a non-frequent crash, you have no ways of fixing it.